# decimal number in my access to datagridview

Tags: database, vb.net, data-binding, datagridview

hi I'm having problem with my database. I'm using access as my database and vb .net 2008.My problem is i change a field into 2 decimal places and when i debug my program why my data in the datagridview not a 2 decimal?
Example : in access TotalCost = 200.00
in vb form datagridview TotalCost = 200

Comment: What happens if you change the value in the DB to 200.01? What is it then in VB.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Me.dataGridView1.Columns("TotalCost").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2"
```

[Format Data in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9x2790s.aspx)